# Configuring kafka topic to contain "last 24 hours" of records

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm looking to configure a Kafka topic such that each record has a TTL of 24hours from when it was first written to when it gets deleted from the topic

Using this page: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs I've looked at a few properties but they all reference the retention of the log rather than individual records.

Is it possible to config a record based TTL on a topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka has a retention policy only for the log ( http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#retention.ms). Kafka cannot delete the record in the middle of the file.

You can play with params http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#segment.ms. It will say how often to create new segments. For example if you create a new file ech 5 mins, then you should see about 24 h + 5 mins of data.

However, it is better not to rely on the Kafka cleaner logic. As it might be delayed (cleaning other topics for example)